# rosinstall error: cannot import name get_vcs_client

Tags: rosinstall

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I've found out that the rosinstall in my robot is not working, basically it says the following:

```
$ rosinstall
ERROR Cannot find rosinstall libraries, check your installation. One frequent cause is that rosinstall 0.5 is still installed in /usr/local/lib. Check the rosinstall wiki for solutions.
cannot import name get_vcs_client
```

- I don't have any rosinstall library in /usr/local/lib
- I've reinstalled rosinstall
- I've done #easy_install vcstools (with no change since they were already there)
- Computer data
- OS: Ubuntu Server 12.04
- ROS: Fuerte 1.8.10

I've been googleing and the only page I've found with the same problem is [this one](http://forums.trossenrobotics.com/showthread.php?5821-workspace-in-ros). But It couldn't help.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/50468/rosinstall-error:-cannot-import-name-get_vcs_client/) by [martimorta](https://answers.ros.org/users/69/martimorta/) on ROS Answers with karma: 843 on 2012-12-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I had the same problem.
first, I updated the packages using
$ sudo apt-get update

then, I installed python-vcstools by
$ sudo apt-get install python-vcstools

I don't know what happened with 'python-vcstools', but the rosinstall works well now.
Hope it will work for you too! :)

Have a nice day!

---

Originally posted by [Oppenheim](https://answers.ros.org/users/3432/oppenheim/) with karma: 41 on 2012-12-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [martimorta](https://answers.ros.org/users/69/martimorta/) on 2012-12-17**:
Thank you, this worked! (I uninstalled everything first)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This also happens when python-vcstools is at an older version than python-rosinstall. Just updating both should solve this. The error message will be changed soon.

Do not mix apt-get installs with easy_install/pip stuff.
Please remove all vcstools from /usr/local/lib/..., because it interferes with the apt-get install of python-vcstools.

apt-get installs rosinstall and vcstools to /usr/share/...
easy_install/pip install them to /usr/local

If you install both, the binary from /usr/share will attempt to load the libraries from /usr/local, so all kinds of problems occur.

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2012-12-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [martimorta](https://answers.ros.org/users/69/martimorta/) on 2012-12-17**:
ok thanks! I'll clean my directories then